# Azure error: DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I am working on the Official Azure sample: [Getting started - Managing Compute Resources using Azure .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-samples-net-management/compute-create-vm/). And getting the following error on line `resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, resourceGroup);` of the following code where app is trying to create a `Resource Group`. I have followed the instructions for Registering an app and from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal) provided by the sample. And, have [assigned a role to app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-a-role-to-the-application) as follows:

[image]

**Error**:

> > Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException
> > HResult=0x80131500
> > Message=DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed.
> > Source=Azure.Identity

> > Inner Exception 2:
> > MsalServiceException: AADSTS70002: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var subscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
    var resourceClient = new ResourcesManagementClient(subscriptionId, new DefaultAzureCredential());

    // Create Resource Group
    Console.WriteLine("--------Start create group--------");
    var resourceGroups = resourceClient.ResourceGroups;
    var location = "westus2";
    var resourceGroupName = "QuickStartRG";
    var resourceGroup = new ResourceGroup(location);
    resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, resourceGroup);
    Console.WriteLine("--------Finish create group--------");

    // Create a Virtual Machine
    await Program.CreateVmAsync(subscriptionId, "QuickStartRG", location, "quickstartvm");

    // Delete resource group if necessary
    //Console.WriteLine("--------Start delete group--------");
    //await (await resourceGroups.StartDeleteAsync(resourceGroupName)).WaitForCompletionAsync();
    //Console.WriteLine("--------Finish delete group--------");
    //Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**UPDATE**:

As per instructions in the sample, following is how I [Used the portal to create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-a-role-to-the-application). I may not have done something right here. Please let me know what I am not doing right here:

**Role Assignment for the registered app in Access Control (IAM)**:

[image]

**Authentication and Direct URI**:

[image]

**API Permissions for the Registered App**:

[image]

**UPDATE-2**:

Working with `@JoyWan`, I was able to resolve the issue (thank you Joy). Below is the screenshot of successful creation of all required `compute resources` including `VM`. **NOTE**: Clicking on the image would provide a better view of the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Where did you run the code?

Comment: @JoyWang I ran the code locally at home in latest version of `VS2019`. I have Azure subscription and I registered an app there as instructed by the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test the code, it works fine on my side. The steps you mentioned are also correct.

In this sample, the [`DefaultAzureCredential()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) actually uses the [`EnvironmentCredential()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet) in local, so if you run the code in local, make sure you have [Set Environment Variables](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-samples-net-management/tree/master/samples/compute/create-virtual-machine#setting-environment-variables) with the AD App `Client ID, Client Secret, Tenant ID`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

From @nam's comment, the issue was that environment vars were not refreshed yesterday, since he had shutdown the machine yesterday and restarted it again today, the environment var got in sync and hence the app started working.

Comment: I think the issue may have to do with me not correctly assigning the permissions to my registered app in Azure. I have added an **UPDATE** section to my post so you can tell me if I correctly [used the portal to create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-a-role-to-the-application)

Comment: @nam I think it is correct, did you add the role to the service principal at the `subscription scope`?

Comment: The registered app has owner role (shown in the first screenshot of the **UPDATE** section). Is that what you are asking? This is how I had done it: Clicked on my Subscription-->Access Control (IAM)-->Clicked on Add button on Add a Role Assignment-->Role: Owner. Assign Access to: Azure AD user, Group, or Service Principal. Select: My Registered App. The screen is similar to what is shown in the first screenshot of my above post before UPDATE section. Did I miss something or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @nam I think all these things should be correct, it is weird, could you make sure the `Client ID, Client Secret, Tenant ID, Subscription ID` are all correct in your environment var? Or could you  create a new AD App to have a try? Without changing any thing, just create a secret for it and add the app as a role in the subscription.

Comment: See UPDATE-2. When I ran the app again after reading your comments today, it started working. So, the issue was that `environment var` were not refreshed yesterday - when I had created the project - since the machine probably needed a re-boot for the `environment var` to start working (get in sync). But since I had shutdown the machine yesterday and restarted it again today, the `environment var` got in sync and hence the app started working. Thank you for walking through the whole process. You may want to make it as `Response` and I'll mark it as an `Answer` so others can benefit, as well.

Comment: Environmental Variables in Visual Studio are only read when the application launches.  If you make changes to those variables like he did, you need to restart Visual Studio for it to make note of the.

Comment: DefaultAzureCredential always attempts to use multiple credential types in a row, including environmental variables, if set.  But if debugging, the Logged in User to Visual Studio will be used first.