# NextJS Azure Services (Auth, SQL Database, Storage Account) Integration Problems

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-msal

I'm attempting to build a [nextjs](/questions/tagged/nextjs) Application with [azure](/questions/tagged/azure) Services that should only be available to users within my [microsoft](/questions/tagged/microsoft) Tenant.  The biggest problem I'm coming across is that database connections are only working from the Static Web App Emulator (localhost:4280) and pulling from a Storage Account Container is only working from localhost:3000.

**Current Resources**

- SQL Server
- SQL Database
- Storage Account
- Static Web App
- App Registered in Microsoft Entra ID

The first thing I did was setup the Static Web App and link it to the Repo which generated the CI/CD Workflow.  Next, I attempted to tackle database.  I created a `staticwebapp.database.config.json` file.
When starting the application with `swa start http://localhost:3000 --run 'npm run dev' --data-api-location swa-db-connection`, I'm able to see data I am pulling in from my SQL Database just fine.

The Storage Account is where it really got messy.  Microsoft states:

"To use DefaultAzureCredential in a JavaScript app, add the @azure/identity package to your application."

```
// connect-with-default-azure-credential.js
import { BlobServiceClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from '@azure/identity';
import 'dotenv/config'

const accountName = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
if (!accountName) throw Error('Azure Storage accountName not found');

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  new DefaultAzureCredential()
);
```

After attempting that, I discovered `DefaultAzureCredential()` does not work in the browser.  You have to use `InteractiveBrowserCredential` which takes in a clientId and tenantId.  I was able to eventually get this working but when moving pieces to a NextJS API Route to protect environment variables, that's where I ran into my next problem.

When I attempt to fetch NextJS API Routes from the emulator (localhost:4280), it's giving me a block in the terminal stating "Function request detected but no endpoint configuration was found.  Please use the --api-location option to configure a function endpoint."  If I use localhost:3000, these API Route calls work just fine.

My next problem is it seems when I use the [interactivebrowsercredential](/questions/tagged/interactivebrowsercredential), the popup window comes up and then in my terminal, I get an error stating `"Token issued for the Single-Page Application client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests"`.

What I'm looking to achieve is implementing [msal2](/questions/tagged/msal2) to authenticate the user right up-front and then attempting to use that authentication for these other Azure Services in a seamless way.

I know I've got multiple different problems in here but any push in the right direction would help immensely.  I've spent days reading documentation and looking for resources but I feel like I'm kind of stuck.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To resolve the error configure the redirect URI in Mobile and desktop applications platform

Comment: @Ryan Use the --api-location option with swa start to specify the location of your API routes. For example: `swa start http://localhost:3000 --run 'npm run dev' --data-api-location    my-api-routes`. the token cannot be redeemed directly in the browser due to security concerns. You need a server-side component to handle token exchange. Implement token exchange logic in your Next.js API route using MSAL to acquire access tokens for Azure [services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msal-overview?view=msal-js-latest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Git [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/13407) concerns the use of Interactive Browser Credential for browser authentication in Identity. If Default Azure Credential is mentioned, it selects the credential based on the environment, as referred to in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62784854/azure-error-defaultazurecredential-authentication-failed).

The code for connecting to Azure Blob Storage using `Azure.Identity` is taken from this [reference](https://dev.to/425show/connecting-to-azure-blob-storage-from-react-using-azure-identity-16l0).

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { InteractiveBrowserCredential } from '@azure/identity';
import { BlobServiceClient, BlobItem } from '@azure/storage-blob';

interface BlobViewProps {}

const BlobView: React.FC<BlobViewProps> = () => {
  const [blobsWeFound, setBlobsWeFound] = useState<BlobItem[]>([]);
  const [containerUrl, setContainerUrl] = useState<string>('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const signInOptions = {
      clientId: 'clientId', // Your application client ID
      tenantId: 'tenantId', // Your Azure AD tenant ID
    };

    const fetchBlobData = async () => {
      try {
        const blobStorageClient = new BlobServiceClient(
          'https://<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/',
          new InteractiveBrowserCredential(signInOptions)
        );

        const containerClient = blobStorageClient.getContainerClient('private');
        const blobList: BlobItem[] = [];

        for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
          blobList.push(blob);
        }

        setBlobsWeFound(blobList);
        setContainerUrl(containerClient.url);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching blob data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchBlobData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>blob name</th>
            <th>blob size</th>
            <th>download url</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {blobsWeFound.map((blob, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>{blob.name}</td>
              <td>{blob.properties?.contentLength}</td>
              <td>
                <img src={`${containerUrl}${blob.name}`} alt={blob.name} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlobView;
```

The Next.js documentation should include a section on configuring CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for API routes. This will enable communication between your application's frontend (localhost:4280) and the API routes (localhost:3000).

- Refer to this to add [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78108141/how-to-handle-rest-api-calls-in-azure-static-web-apps/78119358#78119358) and this for API [configuration](https://github.com/Bawanthathilan/Azure-queue-NEXTJS).
- Microsoft documentation for [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msal-overview?view=msal-js-latest).

[image]